# Unity not working on 14.04 after compiz configurator change

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz

I am new to Ubuntu and probably have a noob problem, but it seems to me to be rather complicated, any help will be appreciated.

I've tried to add opacity property to windows via compiz configurator and suddenly unity has crashed. It won't run after reboot either.

I've tried:

- `compiz --replace`

  It stops on "compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session"
- `compiz --replace cpp`

  It won't load plugin cpp, as it can't find it.
- `unity --replace`

  It doesn't help:

  ```
  "Unknown job: unity-panel service ... No protocol specified ..."
  ```

  Tried to reinstall `unity`, and to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` again no help, still empty screen after login.
- `dconf reset -f  /org/compiz/setsid unity`

  `unity --reset-icons`

  Still no help...

What's interesting here is that on the login stage I do see the top panel (with language, wi-fi etc...), but at the moment I log in, all of that disappears and there is empty screen.

Ubuntu is fresh installed, but I still do not want to reinstall it, as I have already done a lot to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

This thread partly answers the question, but still not full. It really does help when you enaable ccsm, but you'll yet see empty screen even after reboot after the descrubed manipulations. However if you reexecute

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```

everything works fine.. also I'm not very sure if reinstallation of unity, ubuntu-desktop and compiz had made some help here.